# Machine Learning algorithm for similar profiles recommendation (ML.NET library) .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, artificial-intelligence, ml.net

I am searching suitable Machine Learning algorithm for solving matching (similar) profiles recommendation task. I discovered [ML.NET library](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/machinelearning-ai/ml-dotnet) which matches dev-stack (C# and .NET) of my project and would like to use it for this task.

**Description**: Customer searches profiles in the system to perform project. The profiles have qualification skills. The customer makes search by skills required for the project. When some profiles added to the project, It would be helpful to recommend some similar profiles which have skills like already added profile. Therefore, ML should be able to suggest profiles based on list of skills and return users with skills close to existing profiles.

**Research**: I could not find such use-case in [Machine Learning Samples](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/master/README.md) and in list of algorithms of ML.NET library. I tried to use Matrix Factorization ([Movie Recommendation sample](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/MatrixFactorization_MovieRecommendation)) for my use-case but cannot build ML model because it uses different data-set (and perhaps solving different problem).

I'm new in Artificial Intelligence topic and would appreciate opinion from experienced AI developers. I understand that this task can be done with some logic but I hope AI can provide better results.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe clustering could be the answer. You divide your profiles into K groups and you can recommend similar by looking a profiles within the same group as the current and looking at the distance metrics available when using ML.NET for clustering.

Take a look at the [IRIS Clustering sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/iris-clustering) which shows how to categorize flowers into K groups and shows an example of getting distance from that group.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I think it make sense to use clustering for profiles. I will try to implement and update with results.

Comment: Any results @Imaginary?